# Has patent # US6926341 expired due to non-payment?

Tags: maintenance, us6926341

Has patent #US6926341 expired due to nonpayment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true, and it is very easy to get this information using google/patents. If that patent number is entered at [google/patents](http://www.google.com/patents) and you look at the very bottom of the page you will see:

[image]